# Using R lag for Julia

Tags: julia

I am attempting to create a lag +1 forward for a particular column in my data frame.

My data is like this:

```
julia> head(df)
6×9 DataFrames.DataFrame. Omitted printing of 1 columns
│ Row │ Date       │ Open    │ High    │ Low     │ Close   │ Adj Close │ Volume  │ Close_200sma │
├─────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1993-02-02 │ 43.9687 │ 43.9687 │ 43.75   │ 43.9375 │ 27.6073   │ 1003200 │ NaN          │
│ 2   │ 1993-02-03 │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 43.9687 │ 44.25   │ 27.8036   │ 480500  │ NaN          │
│ 3   │ 1993-02-04 │ 44.2187 │ 44.375  │ 44.125  │ 44.3437 │ 27.8625   │ 201300  │ NaN          │
│ 4   │ 1993-02-05 │ 44.4062 │ 44.8437 │ 44.375  │ 44.8125 │ 28.1571   │ 529400  │ NaN          │
│ 5   │ 1993-02-08 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0937 │ 44.4687 │ 45.0    │ 28.2749   │ 531500  │ NaN          │
│ 6   │ 1993-02-09 │ 44.9687 │ 45.0625 │ 44.7187 │ 44.9687 │ 28.2552   │ 492100  │ NaN      

│
```

So this is my attempt at lagging forward, in R I may rep NA, 1 and then append this to the front of the subsetted data. Here is my Julia:

```
# Lag data +1 forward 
lag = df[1:nrow(df)-1,[:Long]]  # shorten vector by 1 (remove last element)
v = Float64[]
v = vec(convert(Array, lag)) # convert df column to vector
z = fill(NaN, 1) # rep NaN, 1 time (add this to front) to push all forward +1

lags = Float64[]
lags= vec[z; [v]]  # join both arrays z=NA first , make vector same nrow(df)
```

When I join the NaN and my array I have a length(lags) of 2. 
The data is split in two:

```
julia> length(lags[2])
6255
```

I see the longer length when access the second portion.

If I join the other way, NaN at end, numbers first. I obtain correct length:

```
# try joining other way
    lags_flip = [v; [z]]

 julia> length(lags_flip)
6256
```

I can also add this back to my data frame: (Nan at bottom, i want at front)

```
# add back to data frame
df[:add] = lags_flip

 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
  [NaN]
```

My question is when joining the Nan and my data like this: 
lags_flip = [v; [z]]

I obtain correct length, when I do it the other way:

Nan first:

lags= [z; [v]]

Then it doesnt appear correct.

How can I offset by data +1 forward, placing a Nan in front and adding back to my df? I feel im close but missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

A a second thought - probably messing with length of column in a `DataFrame` is not the best thing to do and I assume you want a new column anyway. In this case this could be a basic approach:

```
df[:LagLong] = [missing; df[1:end-1,:Long]]
```

or if you want `NaN` (but probably you want missing as explained below):

```
df[:LagLong] = [NaN; df[1:end-1,:Long]]
```

**PREVIOUS REPLY**:

You can do it in place:

```
julia> x = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

julia> pop!(unshift!(x, NaN))
3.0

julia> x
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 NaN
   1.0
   2.0
```

Replace `x` in `pop!(unshift!(x, NaN))` by an appropriate column selector like `df[:Long]`.

Note, however, that `NaN` is not `NA` in R. In Julia `NA` is `missing`. And now there is a branch:

1. if your column allows missing values (it will show `Union{Missing, [Something]}` in `showcols`) then you do the same as above `pop!(unshift!(df[:Long], missing))`.
2. if it does not allow missings you have two options. First is to first call `allowmissing!(df, :Long)` to allow missings and go forward as described above. The other is similar to the approach you have proposed: `df[:Long] = [missing; df[1:end-1, :Long]]`.